RS-485 configure in UARt-2 IMX6ULL
I am using IMX6ULL in tart 2 i was trying to configure RS-485 with gpio as enable pin but i am unable to do so.
Here are the changes i made:
&uart2 {
     pinctrl-names = "default";
     pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_uart2>;
     rts-gpios = <&gpio4 25 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
     rs485-rts-delay = <0 0>;
     status = "okay";
     fsl,dte-mode;
};

pinctrl_uart2: uart2grp {
    fsl,pins = <
    MX6UL_PAD_UART2_TX_DATA__UART2_DTE_RX 0x1b0b1 /* SODIMM 36 */
    MX6UL_PAD_UART2_RX_DATA__UART2_DTE_TX 0x1b0b1 /* SODIMM 38 */
    MX6UL_PAD_CSI_DATA04__GPIO4_IO25 0x10b0
    >;
};

&uart2 {
    status = "okay";
    rs485-rts-active-high;
    linux,rs485-enabled-at-boot-time;
};

After these configurations gpio is not toggling with transceiver process, it goes only high.

See the device-tree documentation Documentation/devicetree/bindings/serial/rs485.yaml. See if the parameters rs485-term-gpios and rs485-rx-during-tx-gpios

@CleitonBueno
i tried as u said but unable to transmit data able to receive data.
have a look on my configurations:
&uart2 {
pinctrl-names = "default";
pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_uart2>;
status = "okay";
rts-gpios = <&gpio4 25 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>; // GPIO4 pin 25 as RTS signal
rs485-rts-delay = <0 0>; // Delay before and after sending data
rs485-term-gpios = <&gpio4 25 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>; // Use GPIO4 pin 25 as RS485 enable pin
fsl,dte-mode;
};
&uart2 {
status = "okay";
rs485-rts-active-high;
linux,rs485-enabled-at-boot-time;
};

Why are there 2 snippets for DT "changes" to the uart2 label? What is the full/complete DT definition for that node? You have only reported a final result, i.e. "gpio ... goes only high". What have you done to debug this? Have you scrutinized the kernel log for relevant messages??? BTW putting DT statements in a comment that obliterates formatting is unreadable and a waste of time. Instead, edit your post.

@prialjoshi I have this implementation on a colibri-imx6ull using uart2 as RS485, but hard reset: &uart2 { pinctrl-names = "default"; pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_uart2>; fsl,dte-mode; /* rts-gpios = <&gpio1 13 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>; */ linux,rs485-enabled-at-boot-time; rs485-rx-during-tx; uart-has-rtscts; rs485-rts-active-high; status = "okay"; }; 

@sawdust I have to use @ DT files because if i will not  configure 2 DT files then UART will not be enabled

Is there is any difference in RS-232 configurations?
